# Come along (Hoist Puller) vs Ratchet Strap

Tags: tools, hardware

Does a Ratchet Strap rated at 10,000 pounds such as [this one](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSufp2JrnkXKG7y_xpv8hkBvy7FLpbm-fhBHN7xTXRT3n2VlUXd) really have 5 times the pulling strenght of a "comealong" winch rated at 2 ton such as [this one](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRo6jeIOzYsZmtc3SqHVfkKCiN5aI0sRmP38ae3ryrZ5HJL2jrQ)?

Ratchet straps are much cheaper, and a few feet of pulling is all I need.

Comment: That would be two and a half times, not five, and is either attributable to the rope composition or hardware design.

Comment: I've unloaded equipment with a ratchet strap.  It's not something you would want to do twice.  You yourself can't put nearly 10,000 pounds of force on a ratchet strap.  When you strap down a load and cinch it with a few hundred pounds of force tops... and the load shifts... the strap will suddenly have thousands of pounds of tensile load.  If it's under 10,000, it will hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be confusing rated working load with the actual ability to pull. The comealong has a much longer lever arm and is therefore better suited to manually pull loads. The ratchet strap, on the other hand, is intended for transport. It's designed to handle dynamic loading of cargo on trucks, etc.

The bottom line is that they serve different purposes and you should select the one that meets your functional needs the best.